# Load Image on specific coordinates on FORM

Tags: vb.net, vba, vb6

Here is my code:

```
Form1.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\User\Desktop\1xxx-LOGO-brand-.jpg", , , 913, 486)
```

I used this code to load a picture successfully. However, the X and Y coordinates did not work. IT load at default coordinates(0,0).a

How should I set the location of a picture to be loaded inside a form?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The X/Y parameters of `LoadPicture()` refer to the width/height to extract from an icon or cursor file.  So it isn't what you want.

Instead, set the `Form1`'s `AutoRedraw` to `True` and `ScaleMode` to `3 - Pixel` and use this line of code:

```
Form1.PaintPicture LoadPicture("C:\Users\User\Desktop\1xxx-LOGO-brand-.jpg"), 913, 486
```